# How to match "(" and ")" parenthesis characters in a regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

I am very new to regex expression.

I want to validate a number like this : 123456789012345678 (123)

I know how to match the first 18 digits for number, but don't know how to allow next ( and numbers inside it)

I am using this function currently that is incomplete, please help me

```
$string = "123456789012345678 (123)";
$pattern = '/^[0-9]{18}$/';
  if(!preg_match($pattern, $string)){
      echo 'valid';
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(` and `)` are regex metacharacters and thus need to be escaped:

```
$pattern = '/^[0-9]{18} \([0-9]+\)$/';
```